# Discrete Math Sets question notably about the power set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help with this problem because I am unsure if I am right or wrong.

Let $A = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\sqrt{3}\}$ and let $\mathscr{P}(A)$ denote the power set of $A$. Describe the set $A\cap\mathscr{P}(A)$ by listing its elements.

So from my understanding $\mathscr{P}(A)$ is$$\{ \{\},\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\sqrt3\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\sqrt{3}\},\{\{\emptyset\},\sqrt3\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\sqrt{3}\}\}.$$

Now $A\cap \mathscr{P}(A)$ would be $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ 
but I am not sure if I am correct on this answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts on this site.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  All you have to do is to check, for each element of $A$, whether it is also a subset of $A$.  No need to write out $\mathscr{P}(A)$

Comment: In particular, you need `\` in front of `{` or `}`, the empty set is `\emptyset`, the intersection is `\cap`, and `\sqrt{3}` gives $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, if it hasn't been specified how the real numbers are modeled as sets, then it is possible that $\sqrt3=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ or $\sqrt3=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$. This is vanishingly unlikely, but you might want to state the assumption that there is no such coincidence.

...and under that reasonable assumption, yes, your answer is right.

By the way, it wasn't necessary to list all the elements of $\mathcal P(A)$. You could have considered each of the three elements of $A$ in turn, and asked whether each is a subset of $A$. This would have saved some time and effort, although perhaps it's just as well to get the practice.

Comment: Thanks! Will take note of that!